# How do I compile RHEL5 compatible shared library from RHEL6 machine with GCC 4.4.6?

Tags: c++, linux, rhel5, rhel6

Note: I'am a C# Windows developer just entering the C++/Linux world.

I have a BOOST based cross platform C++ code which I need to compile as a shared library for:

- Windows
- RHEL6
- RHEL5 and
- Solaris

I have Windows and RHEL6 machines and have successfully built for those. Solaris build currently is not important.

According to this:
[Can I use a shared library compiled on Ubuntu on a Redhat Linux machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774920/can-i-use-a-shared-library-compiled-on-ubuntu-on-a-redhat-linux-machine)

My RHEL6 compiled shared library won't run on RHEL5, because the following command:

```
readelf -s /path/to/your/library.so | egrep 'GLIBC_2.([6-9]|10)'
```

returns GLIBC2.7 dependency:

> 143: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND eventfd@GLIBC_2.7 (14)
>   9069: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND
>   eventfd@@GLIBC_2.7

I was wondering if there is a way to build for RHEL5 through the RHEL6 machine? 
Or any other proposal will do. Thanks.

Comment: The answer you got that command from says *If the output is non-empty, then the library will not work on RHEL-5.*

Comment: Try to bootstrap a rhel5 in a chrooted directory, and build from there.

Comment: A quick Google search yielded this: https://github.com/bbockelm/RHEL5-chroot which seems to have been designed for that purpose.

Comment: Sorry, I meant setup, not bootstrap.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes, that was the primary motivator to ask this question.

Comment: @didierc I'm going to try RHEL5-chroot. thx

Comment: Other options: lxc, docker, xen, or some other virtualization technology (virtualbox for instance is fairly easy to setup, but maybe the other ones are easier to script for automatic builds).

Comment: You can probably use centos instead of rhel if there are existing solutions based on the former but not the later (eg, there are no docker templates on the RH site for RHEL5, but there might be one available for centos5 on the docker site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link your shared library with `-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'` and provide all the required libraries in the same directory.

However, if there is anything in your library headers that use any types from the C++ standard library, you are asking for troubles. The users of your library would have to build and link their applications using the same C++ compiler and the standard library.

The most portable option is to provide a shared library with C API along with C++ header-only wrappers, which users can build using any C++ compiler.

Comment: thanks for the answer. So basically if I understood you well, you are saying the answer is No for a sustainable solution.

Comment: @Visar An example: I use a number of machines with CentOS 6.x at work, the stock gcc is 4.4.7. However, I use my own gcc-4.9.2. gcc-4.4.7 C++ ABI is not compatible with that of 4.9.2, so I wound not be able to use your C++ library compiled with 4.4.7.